# enum acting like an unsigned int in Xcode 4.6 even when enum is defined as a signed int

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have only been able to recreate this bug using xCode 4.6. Everything works as expected using Xcode 4.5

The issue is myVal has the correct bit structure to represent an int val of -1.  However, it is showing a value of 4294967295 which is the value of the same bit structure if represented by an unsigned int. You'll notice that if i cast myVal to an int it will show the correct value. This is strange, because the enum should be an int to being with.

here is a screen shot showing the value of all of my variables in the debugger at the end of main. http://cl.ly/image/190s0a1P1b1t

```
typedef enum : int {
    BTEnumValueNegOne = -1,
    BTEnumValueZero = 0,
    BTEnumValueOne = 1,
}BTEnumValue;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

@autoreleasepool {

    //on this line of code myVal is 0
    BTEnumValue myVal = BTEnumValueZero;

    //we are adding -1 to the value of zero
    myVal += BTEnumValueNegOne;

    //at this moment myVal has the exact bit stucture 
    //of a signed int at -1, but it is displaying it 
    //as a unsigned int, so its value is 4294967295

    //however, if i cast the enum (which should already 
    //be an int with a signing) to an int, it displays 
    //the correct value of -1
    int myIntVal = (int)myVal;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This could be a 32bit/64bit issue: a 32-bit `-1` would become a positive `4294967295` even if you set it into a *signed* but 64-bit integer.

Comment: Change the enum to `typedef NS_ENUM(BTEnumValue, NSInteger) { ... };` and see if that produces expected results.

Comment: @WDUK NS_ENUM gets type as the first argument and name as the second, so your example has to look like `typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, BTEnumValue) { ... };`

Comment: @VitalyS. Apologies, slipped my mind!

Comment: The issue appears to have to do solely with how the debugger is displaying the value. Is that what you're asking about? Or is your program somehow misbehaving?

Answer (score 0):

The new, preferred way to declare `enum` types is with the `NS_ENUM` macro as explained in this post: http://nshipster.com/ns_enum-ns_options/